# MySQL check if Point in Polygon (GeoJSON)

Tags: mysql, gis, geospatial, geojson, wkt

I have a table named **fields** with a column named **geoJSON**. The **geoJSON** column is of type **JSON** which stores an actual GeoJSON object. I am trying to take a list of coordinates which are POINTS (single latitude and longitude) and then select the rows for which the POINTS are in. If a row is return multiple times, a count needs to be returned as well within that row of how many points were contained within the rows **geoJSON** column.

Unfortunately, I cannot even get the GeoJSON column to return as Well-Known-Text (WKT) which can then be used with **ST_Contains** to see if the points are within the **geoJSON** column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The following query provides the following error: *`Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geomfromtext.`*

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_GeomFromText(JSON_EXTRACT(`fields`.`geoJSON`, "$.geometry"))) FROM `fields`;
```

The following query produces this error: *`Geometry byte string must be little endian.`*

```
SELECT ST_AsWKT(`fields`.`geoJSON`->>"$.geometry") AS `polygon` FROM `fields`;
```

The following query does successfully return the **geometry** object inside the **fields** column that is a key within the object.

```
SELECT `fields`.`geoJSON`->>"$.geometry" AS `polygon` FROM `fields`;
```

Thank you

Comment: Try [ST_GeomFromGeoJSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-geojson-functions.html#function_st-geomfromgeojson), see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dchmszO5).

Comment: Excellent @wchiquito! Thank you, that worked splendidly. I appreciate it.